# Django / OAuth2 giving a 401?

Tags: python, django, oauth, reddit

I'm using Heroku to deploy a django based Reddit website app. I've created my app on Reddit for the OAuth ID and key as a "web" app, and tested that Reddit accepts the key via curl. However, my program is not authenticating at all with Reddit, giving a 401 unauthorized access. I've tried regenerating keys, no luck.

The error log is here: http://dpaste.com/2WVSVVW

And the code is here: http://pastebin.com/kPVhRuff

If *anyone* could take a look and see what I've messed up beside the keys, which are sync'd in my Heroku env, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you are not passing the access token while making http call to the reddit URL.

Comment: How would I go about fixing that?